# Is there an elegant way in R to skip a for loop over an empty element?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, null, skip

I want to loop through a list and work with its nth element, but the list can be empty:

```
l <- list()
for(i in 1:length(l)) a <- l[[i]]
```

If the list has 1 element, everything is fine.
But if the list is empty, length(l) equals to zero, so the loop will try to run twice and count down i from 1 to 0. This throws an error, as `l[[1]]` doesn't exist:

```
> Error in l[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Is there a better way to skip the for loop than checking if length(l) is bigger than zero?

Comment: Create a condition to check if it is empty or not `if(length(l) >0) do this`

Comment: This is why `seq_along` is preferred over `1:length()`.

Comment: I found a decent duplicate after answering, which should help funnel more Google searches to a useful answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've stumbled across a "best practice" lesson in R. Generally, people recommend that you write for loops as

```
for (i in seq_along(obj))
```

rather than

```
for (i in 1:length(obj))
```

for precisely this reason. `seq_along(list())` will return `integer(0)`, skipping the loop entirely.

There is also the option of `seq_len` if you only have the length, which may be zero:

```
for (i in seq_len(x))
```

where `seq_len()` will do the right thing when `x = 0` and will return an error if `x <0`, which is usually what you want.